# Line-height and height set to 24px and padding to 0px, but the text is still 1px less from the top than from the bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a link converted to a block using css like that:

```
.button-user-add {
    background: green;
    width: 150px;
    height: 24px;
    display: block;

    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;

    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;

    font-family: Arial;

    line-height: 24px;

    margin-top: 24px;
    padding: 0px;

}
```

But the problem is that the padding from the top is about 1px less than from the bottom.

Why?

How can I fix it?

Comment: can show us the live demo pls......

Comment: according to your css that's fine check to this http://tinkerbin.com/Ai7uxMCQ

Comment: I'm too tired to focus on answering this, so hopefully someone else will come along. I will generalize that it has to do with how fonts actually get rendered. You're only using uppercase letters, but there are other characters in the font that expand past those character's boundaries which are also considered when determining the vertical position of the font inside the box. For example, looking as `INDEX` all the letters have the same height, but if you add a `y` and make `INDEXy`, the height appears to expand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>`font-size:15px` doesn't exist for Arial. The browser will round to either 14px or 16px.</del>

*(**Correction**: Modern browsers now render a wider range of font sizes, including more odd-numbered sizes. Here's a [quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/cRk6L/1/) showing Arial 12px through 22px.)*

The main part of the text (the space occupied by a capital H) is the baseline height. Above that is the ascender (used for accent marks on capital letters), and below it is the descender (used for the bottom of letters like y p and q).

```
font-size = ascender + baseline height + descender
```

The line-height reserves space for the font to be rendered in, but exactly where within that space the text is rendered varies based on the font-family, the font-size, the browser, and (if there's no explicit line-height) the default line-height used by the browser. Within the line-height, the text will be roughly, but not exactly, centered.

As long as there's an explicit line-height, the position of the text usually varies by no more than 1px from browser-to-browser, at least for Arial. But there's no way to force the browsers to render the text more consistently than that.

Comment: There is a difference at least in Firefox for 14, 15, 16 px fonts. 14 is smallest, 15px little bigger and 16px the biggest. I am running Windows 7. Maybe Linux and Mac is not possible of 15 and 16px difference, but Windows machine can render it differently.

Comment: @Derfder: Yep, you're right. This was based on testing done a few years ago. More font sizes appear to be available now, even on Linux. The rest of the info should still hold true. But that's useful to know.